# C#: Nested If else condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using below LINQ Query, now i want to if else condition inside LINQ Query like below- how i can achieve the same ?

```
    if(stemming)
    highlightedText = c.Value.p_content != null && c.Value.p_content[0] != null ? c.Value.p_content[0] : string.Empty
    if(phoentic)
    highlightedText = c.Value.s_content != null && c.Value.s_content[0] != null ? c.Value.s_content[0] : string.Empty
    if(content)
    highlightedText = c.Value.content != null && c.Value.content[0] != null ? c.Value.content[0] : string.Empty
```

Complete code -

```
    var highlightedDataLst = objJson.highlighting.Select(c =>
    new finalOutput
    {
        highlightedKey = c.Key,                                   
        highlightedText = c.Value.content != null && c.Value.content[0] != null ? c.Value.content[0] : string.Empty
  }).ToList<finalOutput>();
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear to me. What do you mean by "I want to if else inside linq"? What´s the problem on your current code?

Comment: The result of your `if(stemming)` statement is always overwritten by the following if/else statement.

Comment: @HimBromBeere : if you see my complete code i want to add above mentioned if else condition inside this code, how this can be achieved in the LINQ query i mentioned ?

Comment: @Erik: No, either of one value will be true at a time

Comment: FYI: You can replace `c.Value.content != null && c.Value.content[0] != null ? c.Value.content[0] : string.Empty` with `c?.Value?.content?[0] ?? string.Empty` for brevity. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: @John: I am using .Net 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm taking a stab at it, it might look something like this:

```
var highlightedDataLst = objJson.highlighting.Select(c =>
new finalOutput
    {
        highlightedKey = c.Key,                                   
        highlightedText = (stemming ? c.Value.p_content?[0] : 
                          (phoentic ? c.Value.s_content?[0] :
                          (content  ? c.Value.content?[0] : null))) ?? ""
}).ToList<finalOutput>();
```

You can simplify your conditions using the null conditional operator (?[]) and null coalescing operators (??).

Comment: So if you have 1000 highlightings it would check the values of stemming a 1000 times, even though you know it will always have the same value?